# Acumatica Mobile Application Approval Error: Unsupported Protocol

Tags: acumatica

We have created a customization to our site that needs approvals. When we go to the mobile application and the Approvals section, we see the item that needs approved but when we go to select the approval item, the following error pops up "*Unsupported Protocol: The communication protocol used by the Acumatica ERP server to which you are trying to connect is not supported by the application. Make sure you use the latest version of Acumatica application.*" Our current site is running 17.206.0030. We can go to the approvals page thru the site and it works fine for the same custom approval. This error only occurs in the mobile application.

[Mobile App Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMWok.png)

Answer (score 0):

Last time I received the same error message in Acumatica mobile app, there was an issue with the changes, that I made in Mobile Site Map. Let me suggest to delete all Mobile Site Map customization files from the local website, restart the mobile app and try to open the Approvals screen on a mobile device.

If there will be no issues with the Approvals screen after you remove all Mobile Site Map customization files, you might consider applying different parts of your Mobile Site Map customization to determine what particular changes are causing this error. And in case of a Mobile Site Map customization built using MSDL, there is also a built-in option to [enable MSDL interpreter logs](https://help.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=051f3624-94e0-436f-b5b5-d0231855294b), which are usually quite helpful to verify no errors have been produced by the MSDL interpreter.

Comment: I have compared our mobilesitermap xml and the files in the mobile folder (the includes and hidden folders) to the mobilesitemap xml and mobile folders, from the files folder in the installer, nothing has changed. I still need to run the MSDL interpreter.

Comment: @MattFortney, could you please advise, if the record you attempted to approve was a standard Acumatica entity or a new entity defined within the Manufacturing suite? Very likely this error is due to the lack of an entry form mapping. When a mobile app attempts to request the mapping for an entry form, it doesn't receive anything in response and therefore shows error **Unsupported Protocol**.