# Unsupported protocol error on Acumatica Mobile

Tags: acumatica

I have enabled Print Sales Order/Quote menu on Acumatica mobile app from Sales Order screen, so user can print the SO from their mobile itself.

I have below code written in mobile sitemap to enable the option but when I click on the link to Print the Sales Order, these error popsup "**Unsupported Protocol: The communication protocol used by the Acumatica ERP server to which you are trying to connect is not supported by the application. Make sure you use the latest version of Acumatica application.**"

```html
<sm:Action Behavior="Record" Context="Record" DisplayName="Print Sales Order/Quote" Name="PrintSalesOrderQuoteReport" Redirect="true"/>
```

[image]

If I remove Redirect option from the above code, the error goes away but it doestn't work either.

I am using Acumatica Version 18.100.0049. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have not worked with the mobile sitemap to be much of help. There was a similar question posted yesterday with an answer today and provides an option to debug the mobile sitemap. See if the answer on this post helps you determine your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116983/acumatica-mobile-application-approval-error-unsupported-protocol

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the mobile app installed?

Comment: Yes I saw that, but seems I know what changes is causing the issue as I add a Redirect option in Action. If I remove it, the error goes away but the menu option does not do anything. Also, I am using the latest mobile app.

Comment: I have even tried uninstalling and installing the Acumatica Mobile App again and checked for any update available. Hence seems I am using the latest.

Comment: Interesting thing now is, I get that error on iOS but not on Android. However, it does not work meaning it does not open the report page as it does in desktop app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please confirm, if you've also mapped the **Sales Order (SO641010)** report form in the mobile site map in addition to the **PrintSalesOrderQuoteReport** action on the **Sales Orders (SO301000)** entry form?

`<sm:Screen DisplayName="Sales Order" Icon="system://Credit" Id="SO641010" Type="Report" Visible="false"/>`